# Parent TabBar Clips Bottom of Children ViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, tabbar

I have a `tabBarController` with a curved `tabBar` via `caShapeLayer`.

My issue is the rectangular frame `tabBar` clips the bottom of children `viewControllers`.

My goal/hope was to go under and clip the bottom by the *curved* frame. See image for reference.

[image]

Any guidance would be really appreciated.

Code for Curved TabBar in TabBarController

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
    
self.view.backgroundColor = .blue
self.tabBar.backgroundColor = .clear
self.tabBar.barStyle = .default
self.tabBar.isTranslucent = false
self.tabBar.clipsToBounds = false
hideTabBarBorder()
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    addTabBarShape()
}

func addTabBarShape() {

let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()

let offset:CGFloat = tabBar.bounds.width/3.5
let bounds: CGRect = tabBar.bounds

let rectBounds: CGRect = CGRect(x: bounds.origin.x, y: bounds.origin.y + (bounds.size.height / 2), width: bounds.size.width, height: bounds.size.height / 2)

let rectPath: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(rect: rectBounds)
let ovalBounds: CGRect = CGRect(x: bounds.origin.x - (offset / 2), y: bounds.origin.y, width: bounds.size.width + offset, height: bounds.size.height)
let ovalPath: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: ovalBounds)
rectPath.append(ovalPath)

shapeLayer.path = rectPath.cgPath
shapeLayer.fillColor = .blue
shapeLayer.shadowPath =  rectPath.cgPath
shapeLayer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
shapeLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.1
shapeLayer.shadowRadius = 20
shapeLayer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: -8)

shapeLayer.shouldRasterize = true
shapeLayer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale

    if let oldShapeLayer = self.tabBarShapeLayer {
        self.tabBar.layer.replaceSublayer(oldShapeLayer, with: shapeLayer)
    } else {
        self.tabBar.layer.insertSublayer(shapeLayer, at: 0)
    }
    self.tabBarShapeLayer = shapeLayer
}

func hideTabBarBorder() {
    self.tabBar.backgroundImage = UIImage.from(color: Constants.style.darkBlue)
    self.tabBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
}

extension UIImage {
    static func from(color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    context!.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
    context!.fill(rect)
    let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return img!
    }
}
```

Comment: From my experience, customized `TabBarController` is a bad idea, if you need a custom shape, you better off create a container view controller with bottom view that shapped like that, and have a container with constraint go past the bottom view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My workaround was drawing the curve at a higher y-point than the tabBar frame...

Answer (score 0):

This is because the child ViewController did not update its constraint, and it is referring to the same tabcontroller constraint. You just need to review the bottom constraint from the controller. I am using snapkit here to fix the constraint before the view appears. You can set the controller bottom margin equal to the superView and handle the tabbar offset inside your controller.

This will basically ignore the presence of the tabbar at the bottom.

```swift
import UIKit
import SnapKit

class SomeViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        updateConstraints()
    }
    
    func updateConstraints() {
        view.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.edges.equalToSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion lucas. i tried it, but still receiving the same UI where the children viewcontrollers are not cut-off by the curved shape, rather the tabBar rectangular frame. any other solution you can advise on?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `backgroundImage` to something not visible to make the view appear to be clipped by the tabbar.

I am not sure why you are explicitly setting it to `UIImage.from(color: Constants.style.darkBlue)` in your example.

The following + copying all your other code is working just fine for me:

```swift
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        addTabBarShape()
        tabBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
        tabBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    }
```

Also make sure that you connect the bottom anchor of the view (e.g. a `UITableView`) **not** to `view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor` (like you normally would do) but rather to `view.bottomAnchor` to make it appear clipped by the tabBar.

(changed some colors in that implementation but here you can see how it clips a `UITableView`)

[image: Screenshot with tabbar clipping a view]